# Python - Chat 2nd client doesn't receive anything until it sends

Tags: python, sockets, chat

Was trying to make a chat application written in Python, but for some reasons I don't know, when the 1st client sends data, it works but the 2nd or other client can't receive it until the other client tries to send a message and it works fine...

Here's my code for the client:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from socket import *
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

'#Connect to Server'
shutdown = False

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 0

server = ("127.0.0.1", 12345)

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

global alias


def sendmsg():
    msg = alias + " : " + chatEntry.get("0.0", END).strip() + "\n"
    #chatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
    #chatLog.insert(END, msg)
    chatEntry.delete(1.0, END)
    #chatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
    s.sendto(msg, server)

def recvmsg(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            while True:
                data = sock.recv(1024)
                chatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
                chatLog.insert(END, str(data))
                chatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
                print str(data)
        except:
            pass

alias = raw_input("Alias ==> ")


root = Tk()

'#Create a window'
frame = Frame(root, width=600, height=450, bg="black")
frame.pack()

'#Create a chat log'
chatLog = Text(root, font=("Determination Sans", 12))
chatLog.insert(END, "Connecting..... \n")
chatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
chatLog.place(x=13, y=13, width=425, height=329)

'#Create list of friends online'
friendsList = Text(root)
friendsList.config(state=DISABLED)
friendsList.place(x=445, y=13, width=142, height=329)

'#Create an entry where you can enter your message'
chatEntry = Text(root)
chatEntry.place(x=13, y=349, width=425, height=96)

'#Create a send button'
btnLogin = Button(root, text="SEND", command=sendmsg)
btnLogin.place(x=445, y=349, width=142, height=96)

'#Set it fixed, not resizable......'
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
root.wm_title("Chat - Underchat")


Thread(target=recvmsg, args=("RecvThread", s)).start()
root.mainloop()
```

And here's my code for the server:

```
from socket import *
import time

'#Put IP here...'
'#Put Socket here...'
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 12345

clients = []

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))

'#Set Blocking to 0 so it will accept basically everything'
s.setblocking(0)

quitting = False
print "server started....."

while not quitting:
    try:
        '#Receive 1024 bytes of data... Its basically 1KB :P '
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if "Quit" in str(data):
            '#Quit if a specified string was detected...'
            quitting = True
        if addr not in clients:
            '#If a new client was found, add them to the clients list'
            clients.append(addr)

        print time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + ": :" + str(data)
        for client in clients:
            '#Send the data to all clients... This is a groupchat afterall :3'
            s.sendto(data, client)

    except:
        '#Try again if something goes wrong.....'
        pass

'#Close the connection when out of the loop'
s.close()
```

So any ideas? Thanks

Comment: One thing I can tell you - if you're mixing threading with GUI mainloops you're in for a bad time. You should be using Tkinter's [`.after` or `.after_idle`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) methods. Combine that with the [`select` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) and life will be much better for you down the road

Comment: Wait so Thread inside tkinter's loop isn't a good idea? Sorry was still new at Python thou.... Lemme take a look at that...

Comment: Tkinter already does its own threading. When you start throwing your own threads into the mix there are a lot of problems that start happening. I learned that the hard way ;)

Comment: @WayneWerner: "tkinter already does its own threading" is false. It doesn't do anything with threads. Tkinter is single-threaded.